# Roman Numeral to Number Conversion in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, roman-numerals

I am new to javascript and am wanting to make a html file that displays the number of days until super bowl "LIV", the current time, and an input for the user to convert a roman numeral into a number. My code is below and as it is now, the countdown element and the time element do not appear when the file is launched. However, When i remove the functions created to convert the roman numeral, both elements appear again. This tells me that the problem with my code is in these functions, however i can't find what/where needs addressing or if i've taken the wrong approach to the conversion all together. I'm wanting the user to type in a roman numeral to the rn text input and when the "Convert" button input is selected, the corresponding number appears in the result span. I am required to use the concept of the algorithm used in the function "toNumber()" however i obviously may have implemented something wrong along the way. any help is appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Roman Numeral Converter</title>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
    <p id="countdown"></p>
    <p id="time"></p>
    <p> Please enter a Roman number (e.g. LIV) to convert to a number: </p>
    <form action="PayslipServlet" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="romannumber" id="rn"> => <span id="result"></span>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Convert" onClick="toNumber()"> <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="empty()">
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function sbCountdown() {

            var countdownDate = new Date("February 2, 2020").getTime();

            var now = new Date();
            var rn = now.getTime();

            var daysLeft = countdownDate - rn;

            var days = Math.floor(daysLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "There are " + days + " days until SUPER BOWL LIV 2020 (February 2, 2020)";

            if(daysLeft < 0) {
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            }

            setTimeout(sbCountdown, 1000);
        }

    sbCountdown();


    function updateClock() {

        var now = new Date(), // current date
        months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
        var dateString = "*** The Current Time is: ";
        var hh = now.getHours();
        var dd = "AM";
        var h = hh;
        if(h >= 12 ) {
            h = hh - 12;
            dd = "PM";
        }
        if( h == 0 ) {
            h = 12;
        }
        time = h + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds() + " " + dd; 

        // a cleaner way than string concatenation
        date = [now.getDate(), 
            months[now.getMonth()],
            now.getFullYear()].join(' ');

        // set the content of the element with the ID time to the formatted string
         document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = dateString + date + " , " + time;

        // call this function again in 1000ms
        setTimeout(updateClock, 1000);
    }

    updateClock();


    function getValue(s) {

        var num = 0;

        if(s == 'I') { num = 1 }
        else if(s == 'V') { num = 5 }
        else if(s == 'X') { num = 10 }
        else if(s == 'L') { num = 50 }
        else if(s == 'C') { num = 100 }
        else if(s == 'D') { num = 500 }
        else if(s == 'M') { num = 1000 }
        else { document.getElementById(result).innerHTML = "Not a Roman Numeral" }

        return num;
    }

    function toNumber() {

        var total = 0;
        var romNum = document.getElementById(rn).value
        var number;


        while(romNum != "") {

            if(getValue(romNum.charAt(0)) >= getValue(romNum.charAt(1)) || romNum.length() == 1) {

                number = getValue(romNum.charAt(0));
                total += number;

                var temp = romNum.slice(1);
                romNum = temp;
            }
            else {

                number = getValue(romNum.charAt(1) - getValue(romNum.charAt(0));
                total += number;

                var temp = ronNum.slice(2);
                ronNum = temp;
            }

        }

        document.getElementById(result).innerHTML = total;
    }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have some syntax errors.

You're missing an ending `)` in  `number = getValue(romNum.charAt(1) - getValue(romNum.charAt(0));`

Also in most of your `getElementById()` elements you're missing quotes around your ids. And you need to change your variable `ronNum` to `romNum` in your `else` block.

Fixing those seemed get some of your functionality to work. You would just need to work on your Reset Button functionality now. Hopefully this helps.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Roman Numeral Converter</title>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
    <p id="countdown"></p>
    <p id="time"></p>
    <p> Please enter a Roman number (e.g. LIV) to convert to a number: </p>
    <form action="PayslipServlet" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="romannumber" id="rn"> => <span id="result"></span>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Convert" onClick="toNumber()"> <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="empty()">
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function sbCountdown() {

            var countdownDate = new Date("February 2, 2020").getTime();

            var now = new Date();
            var rn = now.getTime();

            var daysLeft = countdownDate - rn;

            var days = Math.floor(daysLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "There are " + days + " days until SUPER BOWL LIV 2020 (February 2, 2020)";

            if(daysLeft < 0) {
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            }

            setTimeout(sbCountdown, 1000);
        }

    sbCountdown();


    function updateClock() {

        var now = new Date(), // current date
        months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
        var dateString = "*** The Current Time is: ";
        var hh = now.getHours();
        var dd = "AM";
        var h = hh;
        if(h >= 12 ) {
            h = hh - 12;
            dd = "PM";
        }
        if( h == 0 ) {
            h = 12;
        }
        time = h + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds() + " " + dd; 

        // a cleaner way than string concatenation
        date = [now.getDate(), 
            months[now.getMonth()],
            now.getFullYear()].join(' ');

        // set the content of the element with the ID time to the formatted string
         document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = dateString + date + " , " + time;

        // call this function again in 1000ms
        setTimeout(updateClock, 1000);
    }

    updateClock();


    function getValue(s) {

        var num = 0;

        if(s == 'I') { num = 1 }
        else if(s == 'V') { num = 5 }
        else if(s == 'X') { num = 10 }
        else if(s == 'L') { num = 50 }
        else if(s == 'C') { num = 100 }
        else if(s == 'D') { num = 500 }
        else if(s == 'M') { num = 1000 }
        else { document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Not a Roman Numeral" }

        return num;
    }

    function toNumber() {

        var total = 0;
        var romNum = document.getElementById('rn').value
        var number;


        while(romNum != "") {

            if(getValue(romNum.charAt(0)) >= getValue(romNum.charAt(1)) || romNum.length == 1) {

                number = getValue(romNum.charAt(0));
                total += number;

                var temp = romNum.slice(1);
                romNum = temp;
            }
            else {

                number = getValue(romNum.charAt(1)) - getValue(romNum.charAt(0));
                total += number;

                var temp = romNum.slice(2);
                romNum = temp;
            }

        }

        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = total;
    }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @LukeThomas did this help you? If so, could you upvote and accept this as the answer so that this question can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Here are perhaps the simplest and compact JavaScript functions to convert Roman to Numbers and Number to Roman, which also includes validation -- for example "LV" is 55 but "VL" is not a valid Roman number.

```js
function numberToRoman(val,rom){ //returns empty string if invalid number
  rom=rom||''
  if(isNaN(val)||val==0) 
    return rom;
  for(i=0;curval=[1000,900,500,400,100,90,50,40,10,9,5,4,1][i],i<13;i++)
    if(val >= curval)
       return numberToRoman(val-curval,rom+['M','CM','D','CD','C','XC','L','XL','X','IX','V','IV','I'][i])
}

function romanToNumber(txtRom){//returns NaN if invalid string
  txtRom=txtRom.toUpperCase();
  if (!/^M*(CM|CD|(D?C{0,3}))?(XC|XL|(L?X{0,3}))?(IX|IV|(V?I{0,3}))?$/.test(txtRom))
    return NaN;
  var retval=0;
  txtRom.replace(/[MDLV]|C[MD]?|X[CL]?|I[XV]?/g, function(i) {
    retval += {M:1000, CM:900, D:500, CD:400, C:100, XC:90, L:50, XL:40, X:10, IX:9, V:5, IV:4, I:1}[i]; 
  });
  return retval;
}
```

```css
#tblRoman{border-collapse:collapse;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:.8em}
```

```html
<h3>Roman to Number Conversion</h3>

Enter a Roman Number below, or click on an example button. Then click Convert 
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="example 1" onclick="document.getElementById('romanval').value='LV'">
<input type="button" value="example 2" onclick="document.getElementById('romanval').value='VL'">
<input type="button" value="example 3" onclick="document.getElementById('romanval').value='mmmmmmmcdlxxxiv'">
<input type="button" value="example 4" onclick="document.getElementById('romanval').value='mmmmmmmdclxxxiv'">
<br><br>
<input type="text" size="40" id="romanval">
 <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('resultval').innerText
 = romanToNumber(document.getElementById('romanval').value)" value="Convert"> 
<p />
Resulting Decimal Value: <b id="resultval"></b>

<hr>

<h3>Number to Roman Conversion</h3>
<input type="button" value="Generate table upto 2000" onclick="document.getElementById('tblRoman').innerHTML ='</tr>'+[...Array(2000).keys()].map(x => '<td>'+(x+1)+': '+numberToRoman(x+1)+'</td>'+((x+1)%10==0?'</tr><tr>':'')).join('')+'</tr>'">

<table id="tblRoman" border></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS file with proper code with all cases

```
let romToInt = (string) => {
  const input = string.toUpperCase();
  let output = 0;

  if (input.length === 0) {
    console.log("Please enter a roman number!");
    return;
  }


  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (
      input[i] === "I" ||
      input[i] === "V" ||
      input[i] === "X" ||
      input[i] === "L" ||
      input[i] === "C" ||
      input[i] === "D" ||
      input[i] === "M"
    ) {
      if (input[i] === "I") output = output + 1;
      // I
      else if (input[i] === "V") {
        output = output + 5;
        if (input[i - 1] === "I") output = output - 2;
        // X
      } else if (input[i] === "X") {
        output = output + 10;
        if (input[i - 1] === "I") output = output - 2;
        if (input[i - 1] === "V") return console.log("Invalid number!");
        // L
      } else if (input[i] === "L") {
        output = output + 50;
        if (input[i - 1] === "X") output = output - 20;
        if (input[i - 1] === "I") return console.log("Invalid number!");
        if (input[i - 1] === "V") return console.log("Invalid number!");

        // C
      } else if (input[i] === "C") {
        output = output + 100;
        if (input[i - 1] === "X") output = output - 20;
        if (input[i - 1] === "I") return console.log("Invalid number!");
        if (input[i - 1] === "V") return console.log("Invalid number!");
      }
      // D
      else if (input[i] === "D") {
        output = output + 500;
        if (input[i - 1] === "C") output = output - 200;
        if (input[i - 1] === "I") return console.log("Invalid number!");
        if (input[i - 1] === "V") return console.log("Invalid number!");

      }
      // M
      else if (input[i] === "M") {
        output = output + 1000;
        if (input[i - 1] === "C") output = output - 200;
        if (input[i - 1] === "I") return console.log("Invalid number!");
        if (input[i - 1] === "V") return console.log("Invalid number!");
        if (input[i - 1] === "X") return console.log("Invalid number!");
        // C
      }
    } else {
      console.log(
        "Please enter a valid roman number : ('I', 'V', 'X', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'M')!"
      );
      return;
    }
  }

  
  console.log(`${input} = ${output}`);
};

romToInt("MMCM");
```